# How to get a content of config file for some OSGI Bundle

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, config

I have a following structure:

```
-- bundles
---- nicebundle
------ src
-------- ...
-------- nicebundle.config
---------- NiceConfig.java
-------- ...
----  mybundle
------ ...
----  another bundles...

-- features
----  nicebundle.config.feature
------  rootifles
--------  config.cfg
------  ...
----  another features...
```

In `config.cfg` there are some constants, which I want to use in `mybundle` (in `activate()` method). What I have in `NiceConfig.java` for `nicebundle` is `NiceConfig @interface`, which just mirrorly lists all the content from .cfg file like `String importantString();`, and in .cfg file there is a corresponding record: `importantString=Hello`

For the `nicebundle` you can just load `NiceConfig` object, call the methods and receive the needed constants, like:

```
@Activate
public void activate(final NiceConfig niceConfig) {
    String compositeString = niceConfig.importantString() + " World"; // receive "Hello World"
    ...
```

What I want - to do the same but in `mybundle`. However when I do the same, `niceConfig.importantString()` returns null, not "Hello". I think I miss something very simple and obvious, but my question is: how can I achieve a content of .cfg file, located how I specified above (I cannot change it) in `mybundle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarative Services (DS) will coerce [component properties](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#service.component-component.properties) into an annotation type, like your `NiceConfig` type. But component properties come from the [component description](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#service.component-component.description) and [configurations in Configuration Admin](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#service.component-deployment).

DS does not know anything about some config file in an Eclipse feature. And Eclipse features are not even installed bundles so are not visible at runtime anyway.

You could use an implementation of the [Configurator specification](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.configurator.html) to provision the properties from a resource in your bundle into the appropriate Configuration Admin configuration for your DS component. But this will require some structural changes to move the configuration file from the feature into your bundle.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This indirectly travels me to the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

In short, the right answer for me was to do the following steps:

1. specify new PID in .cfg-File in square brackets, e.g. `[VeryNiceConfig]` and then specify all my parameters after this square-brackets-line, e.g. `VeryNiceInt=42`
2. add `configurationPid = "VeryNiceConfig", configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE` to the `@Component` annotation.
3. and then add my Config `@interface` object as a parameter to the `activate()` method of my bundle and use it for the glory.

This is not working in eclipse, because .cfg-File is added through the feature, and there is no direct injecting into eclipse.exe, but it works after (in my case) maven build.